# Is there a way to create an MJPEG stream from a iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, mjpeg

I was wondering if there is anyone who knows to create a MJPEG stream from your iOS device. For example I want to duplicate my screen from my iPhone t an HTML5 webpage.